# ConEmu: indicate that process exits in the tab?

Tags: conemu

I often run long-running processes in the separate tab in Conemu (-new_console:b).

It would really help if I can see in the inactive tab title, when this process exits/terminated.

Best option I found is to include process name (%n) in the tab title template. This way I can see that process finished running (it shows "?" instead of process name).

But it would really help if instead I can add some suffix, or even better highlight/flash the tab. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append `& ConEmuC -GuiMacro Flash 1 3 10` to the end of your command